# How to let JetBrains Rider to open solution located on shared files?

Tags: windows, git, macos, parallels, rider

I'm using Parallels Desktop on Mac, having a Windows 10 virtual machine on it, but I need to code on Windows to do some .Net related projects.

In order not to put too much load on VM, I want to create a git repo on Mac and open it on VM.

I'm currently using JetBrains Rider on Windows, but the problem is I cannot open the solution which located in Mac. But I can achieve this using Visual studio 2017. (but its too laggy, so I prefer not to use it)

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

@jason-xiao Currently Rider doesn't support open solution from UNC path. But you can attach UNC path as a network drive in your parallels VM then open solution from a network drive in Rider.

Comment: I have the same setup as the OP. There seem to be an issue where network drives are not visible to Rider when elevated (i.e. Run As Administrator). Weirdly, if I run cmd elevated, net use shows the shares correctly.